# Is this function converging or diverging?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show whether or not this function is converging,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n \ln(n)}{{n}^{1/2}+1}$$

I'm using Leibniz' Test and I've shown that
$$\frac{\ln(n)}{{n}^{1/2}+1} \ge 0 \quad \forall n$$

And that as 
$$n \to \infty,\quad \frac{\ln(n)}{{n}^{1/2}+1} \to 0$$

But I'm struggling with the final step, that the function is decreasing. Any help will be greatly appreciated and thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is fine, to conclude let consider

$$f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{{x}^{1/2}+1} \implies f'(x)=\frac{2\sqrt x-\sqrt x \log x+2}{2x({x}^{1/2}+1)^2}$$

which becomes eventually negative for $x\ge x_0$ with

$$\sqrt x_0 \log x_0>2\sqrt x_0+2 \implies \log x_0 >2+\frac2{\sqrt x_0}$$

therefore eventually $\frac{\ln n}{{n}^{1/2}+1}$ is strictly decreasing and the series converges.

Comment: Thanks, that's so much help

Comment: @B.Griffin You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{{x}^{1/2}+1} \\
f'(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{x}(\sqrt{x}+1)-\ln(x)\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}}{({x}^{1/2}+1)^2}=\frac{2\sqrt{x}+2-\ln(x)\sqrt{x}}{2x({x}^{1/2}+1)^2}$$

It is easy to argue that for $x>A$ for some $A$ $f'(x) <0$. You can find such an $A$ for example by making sure that 
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)>2 \\
\sqrt{x} >1
$$